# How to change font size in Xcode 7 IDE (NOT the editor fonts!)

Tags: xcode, ide, font-size

Has anyone come up with a way to change the Xcode 7 IDE (application!) font size (file lists, panels, target info, etc.)?

**NOT the fonts in the editors or console frames (that's trivial)!**

Please note:

- Writing to "defaults" does NOT work.
- Using the Edit->Format->Fonts->Bigger does NOT work.
- Installing a plug-in to change the editor fonts does NOT work.
- Complaining about Apple does NOT work.

Yes, this question has been asked before, but IT HAS NOT BEEN ANSWERED (except for people saying: "I don't know" or "It can't be done" or "Use a different IDE" or explaining how to change editor fonts.

**Please don't reply unless you have a solution.**